# How do I run code based on the true class name of an object?

Tags: php, oop

I am going through a list of objects, all with the same parent class but they could be instances from one of many sub classes.  Depending on the true type of the object I want to perform slightly different operations.

How can I run different blocks of code based on the object types?

In Java I would overload a processing function with each type I wanted to work with, but PHP doesn't allow this.

**Background:**
To Gordon's comment.

We are building forms from a group of objects. A super class Component that is extended to represent specific types of form elements. `TextInput extends Component` and the Component has the ability to hold other Components.  We don't want them to be responsible for their actual representation.

We are working to build HTML right now, but we might potentially want to use them to build .PDFs or other formats.

So we have code that goes through the Components, and recursively through the Components it contains.  Depending on the type of the Component, we need to create different output.

Comment: Please provide more context to your question. It feels like you are asking for a solution to the wrong problem. This rather sounds like misplaced methods to me. Instead of querying the type of the object and then doing something, tell the objects to do something. This is called Tell Don't Ask.

Comment: @Gordon Edited with some background.  We don't want the objects to be responsible for their output, so Tell Don't Ask wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
if($myobject instanceof class1){
}elseif($myobject instanceof class1){
}
```

Or

```
switch(get_class($myobject)){
    case 'class1':
       break;
    case 'class2':
       break;
}
```

Also, make sur you don't break the Open/Closed principle. If you put that portion of code in a class and not in a specific portion of a controller, you end up breaking an important reusability feature of your code:

> Open / Closed Principle
>
> Have you never done a plug-in system? If you did, i’m sure you didn’t
>   ask your users to hardcode a loading line in the code to handle that
>   plug-in right?
>
> Normaly speaking, you’d want your classes to be extendable without
>   needing to change the parent. Extension should be an open principle
>   where adding more code should be as easy as extending but you should
>   never have to modify the parent class.
>
> Thus addind a switch inside the parent or inside another class to handle
>   all possible versions of that class breaks the open principle, because users
>   then have to change the class to add more features...

Comment: Good point about the Open / Closed, but what we're doing is building a representation of a data structure.  Added some background to the question. I added the default inside the method with type hinting that would create a default functionality for any future unknown types.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make an [abstract class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) that represents all of the common functionality of the objects and also dictates what other methods they must have so you can be sure you're working with the same interface every time (these are called [abstract methods](http://www.primitivetype.com/articles/php_5_abstract_classes_and_methods.php)).
2. Then create subclasses for each specific type of object. They *must* implement all of the abstract methods from the main abstract class.
3. Then use the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to dynamically create the proper object based on whatever flag determines the object type (a.k.a subclass).

Answer (score 2):

Try smth like this

```
function objectProcessor_A($o) {}
function objectProcessor_B($o) {}
function objectProcessor_C($o) {}

foreach($objects AS $o) {
    if(function_exist("objectProcessor_" . get_class($o)))
        call_user_func("objectProcessor_" . get_class($o), $o);
}
```

Now, I think, that best solution is using inheritance. Can't change $o's behavior/library code? Than use factory and add method as anonymous function:

```
class OFactory {
    static function getO($type) {
        $r = new $type();
        if($type === "A") {
            $r.processor = function() {...};
        } else if($type === "B") {
            $r.processor = function() {...};
        } else if($type === "C") {
            $r.processor = function() {...};
        }
        return $r;
    }
}

$a = OFactory::getO("A");
call_user_func($a->processor);

$b = OFactory::getO("B");
call_user_func($b->processor);
```

Comment: This works pretty well, but considering Mathieu's answer it allows for a default functionality.  If I have 30 different objects and only 5 of them are special cases, the rest can fall back to the `default:`